# ArcGIS JavaScript v4 - KML via FeatureLayers

Tags: kml, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Now i'm aware there's no KML module in 4.0 beta but this blog http://odoe.net/blog/diy-kml-in-arcgis-js-api-4-beta/ has a pretty nice way to overcome this. Unfortunately not working for me.

[fiddle] https://jsfiddle.net/ytsycg5r/

1) I use "//utility.arcgis.com/sharing/kml" to convert kml to feature set
2) use GroupLayers to create featurelayers and add to map.

I get error "esri/request: the first parameter should be a url string"